# What is binomial expansion of complex functions?

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

Can someone explain how does this expansion has come? I have searched my whole book, no where has got explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was obtained fractoring $\omega$ in de denominator
:
$$\frac1{\omega-z}=\frac1\omega\,\frac1{1-\cfrac z\omega}$$
and expanding the second fraction as the geometric series in $\dfrac z\omega\:$ (this supposes $|z|<|\omega|$).